# 'method' object is not subscriptable. Don't know what's wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some code to create an unsorted list but whenever I try to insert a list using the insert method I get the 'method' object is not subscriptable error. Not sure how to fix it. Thanks.

```
class UnsortedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.theList = list()
    def __getitem__(self, i):
       print(self.theList[i])
    def insert(self, lst):
        for x in lst:
            try:
                self.theList.append(float(x))
            except:
                print("oops")


myList = UnsortedList()
myList.insert[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 57):

You need to use parentheses: `myList.insert([1, 2, 3])`.  When you leave out the parentheses, python thinks you are trying to access `myList.insert` at position `1, 2, 3`, because that's what brackets are used for when they are right next to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class UnsortedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.theList = list()
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        print(self.theList[i])
    def insert(self, lst):
        for x in lst:
            try:
                self.theList.append(float(x))
            except:
                print("oops")


 myList = UnsortedList()
 myList.insert([1, 2, 3])
```

This will work.
While making object of class your forgot to put parenthesis.