# x = np.array(data.drop[predict], 1) gives 'method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, object, methods, typeerror

i wrote this code, and for some reason: `x = np.array(data.drop[predict], 1)`, gives me 'method' object is not subscriptable

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

data = pd.read_csv("Book1.csv", sep=",")

data = data[["primeiro", "segundo", "terceiro", "quarto", "quinto", "um", "dois"]]

predict = data

x = np.array(data.drop[predict], 1)
y = np.array(data[predict])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()

linear.fit(x_train, y_train)

acc = linear.score(x_test, y_test)

print(acc)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['method' object is not subscriptable. Don't know what's wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261055/method-object-is-not-subscriptable-dont-know-whats-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Your `predict` value is wrong, it is basically overlapping itself. Did you mean `predict = data`?

Comment: I did a similar project. In your case I did predict = "primeiro" (just an example). If you are training your dataset, predict should be one column etc.