# 'method' object is not subscriptable. I don't know which is wrong

Tags: python

Can someone help me where I got it wrong

```
data_pad = []
for key in np.unique(df['unique-key']):
    data_pad += [df[df.reindex[:, 'unique-key'] == key].reindex[:, ['distance', 'direction', 'gridID']]]
```

Comment: `reindex` is a method. It should be called with `()`, putting the arguments inside the parentheses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['method' object is not subscriptable. Don't know what's wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261055/method-object-is-not-subscriptable-dont-know-whats-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use [DataFrame.reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method with wrong syntax.

Here an example from link

`df.reindex(new_index, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand the error. First - what subscriptable mean? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not) you can find detailed answer but in general it means object can be called with `[]` syntax

```
l = [1,2,3]
print(l[0]) # works, l is subscriptable
x = 5
print(x[0]) # TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

We are close, so now we know that we use `[]` on object that is not subscriptable, and as error says, that object is method

```
class A:
    def my_method(self, param):
        print(param)


a = A()
a.my_method(0) # prints 0
a.my_method[0] # TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

Voila! We can now suspect our problem is because we use some method with square brackets instead of classic one. As other suggested, it's [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method